# Set KEY and Value in Local Storage for the URL loading in Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to set KEY and Value in Local Storage for url loading in Edge Browser.

I have tried in 2 ways but still not able to set KEY and Value, i am getting Null Pointer Exception.

[image]

I am trying in Selenium.

Kindly help me to set KEY & VALUE

1st WAY:
public void setLocalStorage()
{

```
        LocalStorage local = ((WebStorage) driver).getLocalStorage();    
        local.clear();
        local.setItem("route", "A");
 }
```

2nd WAY:

```
@Test
public void setLocalStorage(String key, String value) {         
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;         
js.executeScript("LocalStorage.setItem(arguments[0],arguments[1])",key,value);     }
```

Comment: Issue has been resolved.

Comment: LocalStorage localStorage = ((WebStorage) driver).getLocalStorage();
  localStorage.setItem("Shell",
    "{\"locationnum\":\"****\",\"devicenum\":\"***\",\"storelang\":\"en-us\",\"computername\":\"*****\",\"trainingmode\":\"***\"}");
  localStorage.setItem("Route", "B");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.navigate().refresh();